# Все переменные становятся null после вызова метода

Tags: c#, .net, list, null, runtime

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть 2 листа files и reserver, они заполняются данными
в форич при вызове метода DocumentModel.Load все переменные обнуляются включая листы

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        else return;
        (int, int) asd = new(5, 5);
        List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>(new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).GetFiles());
        List<FileInfo> reserved = new List<FileInfo>(new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).GetFiles());

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
            DocumentModel doc = DocumentModel.Load(file.FullName, LoadOptions.DocDefault);//строка после которой все переменные и списки с массивами становятся null
            Console.WriteLine(asd.Item1 + asd.Item2);
            Console.WriteLine(doc.Content.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что делает `DocumentModel.Load`? Может этот метод окна перегружает, и в частности вашу форму? Или создаёт новую форму. Короче, нужно разобраться, что там происходит вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Обернул в try cath. Выяснилось что когда выскакивает исключение сам Visual Studio освобождает память поэтому и было null

Comment: А, ну да, если исключение, то вы вылетаете на самый верхний уровень программы и переменные внутри функций конечно утилизируются.